# Can't display CSS badge overlaid on Font Awesome icon

Tags: html, css, woocommerce

So, I'm trying to get an item count badge to display overlaid on my cart icon in the header.  I'm using this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22736017/85721) as inspiration.

I've edited the theme to include the `data-count` element, and I've got what I think is correct CSS being served, but nothing ever shows up - but in a JSFiddle, it displays just fine.

The site is https://wolfsrawfood.com/.  The cart icon appears in a sticky banner after the page is scrolled.  I'm sure I've just got some style somewhere stomping on this, but I can't figure it out.  Any help or pointers would be awesome.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2x7qnLv3/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The problem

You want to use pseudo-elements (i.e., `::after`) on `<svg>` element. This is not possible and was asked [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358051/using-pseudo-elements-on-svg-sub-elements) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61277039/is-there-a-way-to-use-pseudo-element-before-after-in-svg-path) on StackOverflow.

To see that this is the case, just move your CSS from `<i>` to `<svg>`.

**Pseudo-element `::after` on `<i>` --> working ✔**

```css
i {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: static;
  color: #296199;
}

.cartbadge::after {
  content: attr(data-count);
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(64, 64, 64, 1);
  height: 2rem;
  top: -1.25rem;
  right: 0.5rem;
  width: 2rem;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2rem;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #404040;
}

.cartbadge[data-count="0"]::after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" integrity="sha512-xnwMSDv7Nv5JmXb48gKD5ExVOnXAbNpBWVAXTo9BJWRJRygG8nwQI81o5bYe8myc9kiEF/qhMGPjkSsF06hyHA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<i data-count="5" class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-2x cartbadge"></i>
```

**Pseudo-element `::after` on `<svg>` --> not working ✖**

*Note: It's exactly the same code as above!*

```css
svg {
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: static;
  color: #296199;
}

.cartbadge::after {
  content: attr(data-count);
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(64, 64, 64, 1);
  height: 2rem;
  top: -1.25rem;
  right: 0.5rem;
  width: 2rem;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2rem;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #404040;
}

.cartbadge[data-count="0"]::after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" integrity="sha512-xnwMSDv7Nv5JmXb48gKD5ExVOnXAbNpBWVAXTo9BJWRJRygG8nwQI81o5bYe8myc9kiEF/qhMGPjkSsF06hyHA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<a href="/cart/">
  <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-shopping-cart fa-w-18 fa-2x cartbadge" data-count="8" aria-hidden="true" data-fa-processed="" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="shopping-cart" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512">
    <path fill="currentColor" d="M528.12 301.319l47.273-208C578.806 78.301 567.391 64 551.99 64H159.208l-9.166-44.81C147.758 8.021 137.93 0 126.529 0H24C10.745 0 0 10.745 0 24v16c0 13.255 10.745 24 24 24h69.883l70.248 343.435C147.325 417.1 136 435.222 136 456c0 30.928 25.072 56 56 56s56-25.072 56-56c0-15.674-6.447-29.835-16.824-40h209.647C430.447 426.165 424 440.326 424 456c0 30.928 25.072 56 56 56s56-25.072 56-56c0-22.172-12.888-41.332-31.579-50.405l5.517-24.276c3.413-15.018-8.002-29.319-23.403-29.319H218.117l-6.545-32h293.145c11.206 0 20.92-7.754 23.403-18.681z">
    </path>
  </svg>
</a>
```

## The solution

Make a wrapper and use `::after` on it. You need to adjust your code so that `content: attr(data-count);` will work (in the example below I hardcoded `content: '1';`). Also, you might need to adjust CSS, but I solved the problem you were asking about.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

svg {
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: static;
  color: #296199;
}

.wrapper::after {
  content: '1';
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(64, 64, 64, 1);
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  top: -15px;
  right: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  line-height: 1.1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #404040;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" integrity="sha512-xnwMSDv7Nv5JmXb48gKD5ExVOnXAbNpBWVAXTo9BJWRJRygG8nwQI81o5bYe8myc9kiEF/qhMGPjkSsF06hyHA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<a href="/cart/">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-shopping-cart fa-w-18 fa-2x cartbadge" data-count="8" aria-hidden="true" data-fa-processed="" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="shopping-cart" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512">
      <path fill="currentColor" d="M528.12 301.319l47.273-208C578.806 78.301 567.391 64 551.99 64H159.208l-9.166-44.81C147.758 8.021 137.93 0 126.529 0H24C10.745 0 0 10.745 0 24v16c0 13.255 10.745 24 24 24h69.883l70.248 343.435C147.325 417.1 136 435.222 136 456c0 30.928 25.072 56 56 56s56-25.072 56-56c0-15.674-6.447-29.835-16.824-40h209.647C430.447 426.165 424 440.326 424 456c0 30.928 25.072 56 56 56s56-25.072 56-56c0-22.172-12.888-41.332-31.579-50.405l5.517-24.276c3.413-15.018-8.002-29.319-23.403-29.319H218.117l-6.545-32h293.145c11.206 0 20.92-7.754 23.403-18.681z">
      </path>
    </svg>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: This looks promising.  I'll try it out later when I've got access to that site again.  Thanks!